# Not getting results in related tables using EF 5 and MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-relationship

Brand new to C#/ASP.NET...

I have 2 tables: Administrators and AdministratorsRights. In the Administrators table, each Administrator has an AdministratorsRightsID. This is my Administrators class (model):

```
public partial class administrator
{
    [Key]
    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AdministratorsRightsID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StandardID { get; set; }

    public virtual administratorsright RightsLevel { get; set; }

}
```

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.administrators.ToList());
}
```

This is my view (Razor):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RightsLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StandardID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new { id=item.AdministratorID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "details", new { id=item.AdministratorID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delete", new { id=item.AdministratorID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Everything shows up except for the item.RightsLevel in the view. I am trying to get it to show the name as opposed to the ID (System Administrator, not "1"). I'm not surprised this isn't working because I haven't told it which column to look at but the problem is, I don't know where to do that. I'm guessing my model isn't correct as I would suspect that all this logic should occur there.

Comment: where is the mapping between "1" and "administrator" defined?

Comment: @paul, it is defined in the AdministratorsRights table.

Comment: have you `Include`d administrators rights in your LINQ query? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx)

Comment: @paul, sorry you kind of lost me. I really don't know anything about LINQ but I thougth EF was an alternative to LINQ so am I even using LINQ? I'm not even sure where this query would be. hmm.

Comment: Instead of `db.administrators.ToList()` try `db.administrators.Include("administratorrights").ToList()`

Comment: that didn't work. got this error = "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'SmartPrintModel.administrator' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'administratorsright'."

Comment: even with the 's' on the end?

Comment: yep, even with the 's'. the table name is administratorsrights, the class name is administratorsright. wasn't sure which it was looking for so tried both.

Comment: sounds like your model is unaware of the relationship between the tables. The navigation property is usually added automatically if there is a referential integrity constraint in the database. If it is not there, you should try adding it manually using the model editor.

Comment: @Progger LINQ just stands for language integrated query. It does not specify whether you use it with in memory objects or with databases trough an ORM (like EF). Usually when you work with memory objects you talk about "linq-to-objects", with Entity Framework you talk about "linq-to-entities".

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on your AdministratorRights table, and what fields you have. The good news is that you can go to further levels in the DisplayFor helper to have it pull the correct field:

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RightsLevel.RightsLevelName)`

Where `RightsLevelName` is the actual name of the field that you are trying to show.

Comment: That is good news! Didn't know that. Fixed that but still not getting anything back for that column.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Nope. Just a blank spot where there should be data.

Comment: Are you getting back the information from the database? Try putting `db.administrators.ToList()` in a separate variable and see if AdministratorRight is being populated.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do that would require another SO question from me. If you could point me somewhere that shows how to check to see if my queries bring back data, that would be really helpful.

Comment: You should learn how to debug in Visual Studio: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging